# How do I save data to Internal Storage\Android\data\com.myappname for a android FMX app?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I would like to save if the user enabled dark mode for the application so it can be re-loaded when the app is opened again.

This is something that should be saved in the applications android data folder. What's the best way I could do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the

[TPath.GetDocumentsPath](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath)

to get the location, and then you could use

[TIniFile](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile)

to load/save the information.